# Spring app on Tomcat doesnt find class in weblogic.jar

Tags: java, tomcat7, noclassdeffounderror, weblogic-10.x, spring-3

I'm trying to deploy an app on tomcat 7 that uses spring 3.1.1 and weblogic 10.3, but I keep getting a NoClassDef exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.jndi.Environment at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

I've double checked and and the weblogic jar is present on WEB-INF/lib and it does contain said class:

```
jar tf WEB-INF/lib/weblogic.jar | grep /Environment.class
weblogic/cluster/messaging/internal/Environment.class
weblogic/jndi/Environment.class
org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Environment.class
```

this happens when a spring bean factory tries to build this bean on my root-context.xml

```
<beans:bean
    id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    p:jndiTemplate-ref="jndiTemplate"
    p:jndiName="weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
```

I thought it might be some classpath issue, but I have been playing around with the MANIFEST.MF of the webapp and this problematic jars(spring & weblogic) for a while now,  without any luck.
Any ideas on what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe using `weblogic.jar` directly in the classpath does not work. You need to create `wlfullclient.jar` and put it in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Follow the instructions given here: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=558